# Why is hashed password not matching from value in database?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, hash, sha256

I have a registration form whose snippet is as follows-

```
$email=$_GET['email'];
$pass=$_GET['pass'];
$salt = dechex(mt_rand(0, 2147483647)) . dechex(mt_rand(0, 2147483647));
        $password = hash('sha256', $pass.$salt);
        for($round = 0; $round < 65536; $round++) 
        { 
            $password = hash('sha256', $password.$salt);
        }
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO user_tbl(email, password, salt) VALUES ('$email','$password','$salt')");
```

For a specific password following string is getting stored in db-

```
df22e53c7fb2d599d64597a04fd28ca47bc79675ac50a2381c9a17fd4e07b263
```

Now i also have a login form. Whose code snippet is as follows-

```
$email=$_GET['email'];
$pass=$_GET['password'];
$result=mysql_query("SELECT * from user_tbl where email='$email'");
$row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
$salt = $row['salt'];
$password = hash('sha256', $pass.$salt);
for($round = 0; $round < 65536; $round++) 
   { 
       $password = hash('sha256', $password.$salt);
   }
if(strcmp($row['password'],$password)!=0)
{
    echo "wrongpassword";
    exit();
}
else
{
    echo "Success";
}
```

Now i could see that the hashed password which the login form is evaluating to is also `df22e53c7fb2d599d64597a04fd28ca47bc79675ac50a2381c9a17fd4e07b263` . Which is same as what registration form is submitting to database.
They should match. But they are not. The String compare test is always failing.
The length of both fields i.e. password and salt are 200 each and are of type VARCHAR which is sufficient i think because above algo will generate a 64 character long string only. Still What is the problem? Please help me out here.

Comment: Why wouldn't you just use bcrypt (via `password_hash()`)?

Comment: The best help I think we can give is to tell you to stop what you're doing. First, use the PHP [password API](http://php.net/password) instead of trying to roll your own. Second, stop using `mysql_*` functions are they were deprecated years ago and are removed in PHP 7, get with the times and start using PDO. Third, you're open to SQL injections attacks, so while using PDO, also us its prepared statments support. Fourth, do not pass plain text passwords in the URL.

Comment: Do not develop your own password security algorithms unless you want the kind of publicity gained by Ashley Madison, and a few years back by linked in and adobe. Do not reinvent the flat tire. Use the PHP password algorithm. It's designed to be somewhat future proof, where the future offers cheaper and cheaper computer power in the hands of cybercrooks. Seriously.

Answer (score 0):

You just need a simple correction in your IF condition:

```
if(strcmp($row['password'],$password)!==0) // change here :)
{
    echo "wrongpassword";
    exit();
}
else
{
    echo "Success";
}
```

Please see the documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strcmp.php